# How to styling chart in ggplot like charts below?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made pie chart using ggplot2 with style and color in image 1. I use `geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") + coord_polar("y", start=0)` to make it.

[image]

However, I got a request to style and color the chart like in image 2.

[image]

How to do it in ggplot2 using R language? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this specific styling is an option in ggplot2. My best bet would be to export the ggplot2 plot as .svg or .pdf file and add these effects in illustrator/gimp or photoshop.

Comment: One of the ggplot2 maintainers on 3d plots: https://serialmentor.com/dataviz/no-3d.html - although admittedly, this particular pie chart which you are showing would also fall into what would be considered an "accurate representation of the data"... ggplot2 does in general not seem to support "fancy patterns" (like shadows, or gradient fills), because I guess it follows the idea that any aesthetic should represent some dimension of your data.

Comment: Thank you teunbrand and Tjebo for your edit and reply.